# ASP.NET Membership setup - Database problems

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-config, membership

I am setting up a membership provider, and as a result, I am getting the following error message:

> ```
> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file
> ```
>
> C:\Users\Mcoroklo\Desktop\Programmering\Private
>   Projekter\ASP.NET\Helpdesk\Version4\HelpDesk\ClientSite\App_Data\ASPNETDB.mdf
>   failed. A database with the same name
>   exists, or specified file cannot be
>   opened, or it is located on UNC share.

I am new to setting up membership so I can't deny something really crucial is missing! :-)

I am quite sure this has something to do with my connection string and/or SQL Membership provider. I've the following setup in my web.config:

**My connection string:**

```
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="MembershipServer" connectionString="Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ASPNETDB.mdf; Trusted_Connection=Yes;"/>
```

**My SQL provider**

```
 <membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add connectionStringName="MembershipServer" 
         name="AspNetSqlProvider"
         applicationName="/" 
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

**My authentication and authorization:**

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">

  <forms name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" loginUrl="Site/Login.aspx"
      cookieless="UseCookies"  >
  </forms>
</authentication>

<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

The file structure in my website is I've two local databases in my directory. The membership one (ASPNETDB.MDF) is the one i point at with my connection string. I've used the ASP.NET tool to create it.

The other database I connect to via LINQ TO SQL classes and is in a different project (using tier layers).

Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: have you opened the DB using some other program?

Comment: Are you running this in your local development environment?

Comment: seems like you are working too hard when you don't need to. start with a fresh site and run the configuration.  Until you are familiar with the provider based membership features and NEED to customize behavior, there is no need to confuse things by duplicating the default behavior. am i making sense?  e.g. the values you are providing show that you in reality should be using the default configurations which are in machine.config.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio will initialize all of that for you. You are getting in it's way. It has yet to create and provision that database for you.

Delete the connection strings element, the membership element, the authentication element and the authorization element.

or better yet **Start with a fresh Asp.Net Application**

Then click Project(or website)> Asp.net Configuration and follow the steps.

otherwise you will need to create and provision your own db with aspnet_reqsql.exe.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the \ before the database name.

AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|ASPNETDB.mdf

instead of:

AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ASPNETDB.mdf

Oh and another thought, you do have SQL Express loaded on the machine, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that machine.config defines a Connection String with the name "LocalSqlServer" and by default your app will use that.

To fix the problem, either explicitly remove the name like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
    <!-- your new connection string here -->
</connectionStrings>
```

or use clear, but I haven't tested it:

```
<clear/>
```

Usually what I do is just overwrite the LocalSqlServer, so my connection string is named the same, that seems to fix most problems.

Like others have mentioned, you are attaching the ASPNETDB when it should do that for you when you setup your app using the ASP.NET Site Manager.

Comment: Tried both. But .Net 4's machine.config file overrights the changes. So, no good.

Comment: All local web.config should override the machine level config, at least it always has in my experience. I would double-check your tags are all in the same places and there's no spelling mistakes. Restarting the App Pool won't hurt either.